# Tools to view partial data that arrived at the browser

Tags: php, performance, flush

I'm using flushing technique to flush  of my page from server to improve performance. Are there any tools available which let me look in to the partial data that has arrived at the browser end?

Comment: Your browser does already. It shows what has arrived (if it's able to show). What are you trying to find out, can you specify this a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fiddler has an option to do it